# Needs to compile the missing `detour 3.0` lib in Visual Studio

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, detours

I am going to compile old project(visual studio 2012 platform-v110xp) in visual studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2019.

It's using `boost` and Microsoft `detour 3.0` libraries.
But the `detour 3.0` has been deleted accidentally.
And now I can only find `detour4.0`.

But I get an error like this

[image: detour4.0 error]

How do I get the `detour 3.0` lib?

Answer (score 0):

C++ Static Libraries built with VS 2015, VS 2017, or VS 2019 are "binary compatible", but that's not true of any other versions of Visual C++. For example, a static library that links with VS 2012 won't necessarily work when linked with VS 2013 code. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017).

I don't know exactly what toolsets are involved but that's the likely cause of the link issues. The main thing is to make sure all the static libraries and main executable is built by the same compiler version.

> Note that DLLs and their export libraries typically use only "C-style" binding so they can be binary compatible with multiple generations of compilers.

VS 2019 includes the `v141_xp` platform toolset (i.e. the VS 2017 compiler using the Windows 7.1A SDK that is compatible with Windows XP / Windows Server 2003).